# Improvement of generic inferring of the type of a deeply nested property

Tags: typescript

eI have a generic function correctly inferring types of deeply-nested property, but only in the cases when the root object is passed into it.

Is there a way to improve the function to make it work without passing the root object (e.g. by defining the type of the object as a generic parameter)?

Here is the code (the working part and the non-working):

```js
// WORKING PART

type Flatten<T, O = never> = Writable<Cleanup<T>, O> extends infer U ?
    U extends O ? U : U extends object ?
    ValueOf<{ [K in keyof U]-?: (x: PrefixKeys<Flatten<U[K], O>, K, O>) => void }>
    | ((x: U) => void) extends (x: infer I) => void ?
    { [K in keyof I]: I[K] } : never : U : never;

type Writable<T, O> = T extends O ? T : {
    [P in keyof T as IfEquals<{ [Q in P]: T[P] }, { -readonly [Q in P]: T[P] }, P>]: T[P]
}

type IfEquals<X, Y, A = X, B = never> =
    (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
    (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? A : B;

type Cleanup<T> =
    0 extends (1 & T) ? unknown :
    T extends readonly any[] ?
    (Exclude<keyof T, keyof any[]> extends never ?
        { [k: `${number}`]: T[number] } : Omit<T, keyof any[]>) : T;

type PrefixKeys<V, K extends PropertyKey, O> =
    V extends O ? { [P in K]: V } : V extends object ?
    { [P in keyof V as
        `${Extract<K, string | number>}.${Extract<P, string | number>}`]: V[P] } :
    { [P in K]: V };

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]

function lookup<T, K extends keyof Flatten<T>>(obj: T, key: K): Flatten<T>[K];
function lookup(obj: any, key: string) {
    const i = key.indexOf(".");
    return (i < 0) ? obj[key] : (lookup as any)(obj[key.substring(0, i)], key.substring(i + 1));
}

function lookupWithValue<ObjectType, DeepKeyType extends keyof Flatten<ObjectType>>(obj: ObjectType, key: DeepKeyType, value: Flatten<ObjectType>[DeepKeyType]): void {
    // SOME LOGIC
}

// SHOWCASE

const foo = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: 10
        }
    },
    d: [
        0,
        {
            e: {
                f: "f"
            }
        },
        "20"
    ]
};

type FooType = typeof foo;

lookupWithValue(foo, "a.b.c", 10); // OK! Correct, because (number type == number type)
lookupWithValue(foo, "a.b.c", "10"); // ERROR! Correct, because (string type != number type)

// =====
// NOT WORKING PART
// =====

// Is there a way to create a method, which doesn't require the root object to be passed into ???
function lookupWithValueWithoutObject<ObjectType, ...>(key: ???, value: ???): void {
    // SOME LOGIC
}

lookupWithValueWithoutObject<FooType>("a.b.c", 10); // OK
lookupWithValueWithoutObject<FooType>("a.b.c", "10"); // ERROR
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUHkCUGkEkByBxUAFAgtAKgKFwC4CeADgKagBiANgIYEFkB2APNgDSiSgC8oTZAG5kATgD5eEEQEsCtAEbUyLAMJLaTAK4k2YzpAlkAHoyYATAM6hpTAGajQAVVAB+XKA9PQx05a6uvAC4vH2Y-AHt5ACsyAGMCV3dPADVaak0ySFsWAG9QAG1YayZQAGsyInDbJwBdAFoXYIAKI2C0ETJbaSNYCosWGnpTFkdCmv09UFgJgEpeCUFw6TNQAF8xJI8AH1AmluDHOZ4FpbM50PMrfeL7EVB4I5PlxM9QPMLisoqq+5rg+DGa1AwQEwjuB2B-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-2A8DP2gIIaQZOFkPDDDn1o2I+TY0DFRozUYX46cbwkiAoAAMqQAAsvSoAADKQMg8AqBduCs2zAASkDgCoGBs-S+AFUwRW2I5kh5Z4tBEjRnjyFra766AsTBL6ebax4mqvKs7AkmYwT5GbPXWwbzPO68ZB667+u2ME1W2NVDuWw7VsO9VAZ5v7rwWasumIpQjlo5I34-Cr4QpndJAPQQz2E2QTQp5w1W0IJ8iCbE1WcCbDWgKzkCwAAhOm4QiB08ScMesS0JoFgUE0-F3N+vB8H3oDfjMuDp5n2cGXnjkF0XJdlwXJv1TC1dgPS0DQDADcqE3LcEG3cSd93ux7SPaZ10P8mXuf5Bj6LYA8E-T8P6AiCQJiUBwEgqCYDgr-Pxfq-eAVgs6iAoLQUAdZaBSgIOEQ2IpGCzlAAeMgWdwhmE4HWR60hYiPVAB2AA5AkAQZAVhgIIijBIcDQDHlACQGk3cVg2BoS4NhuBYrxVuo5Uak8XpkEnuETQBAyYsVEXDcgnBBLSL8sFVwbDOAEwMsENhLgGaLGeOrDwYsuY835oLYWmpx48Puk9fhgjhHiIGPHeGNV56l3LidXqq8a6wGMUlDOZic4WJEVQ6x4QKZ2OLg4pe4cq6sw3lvaAuAgA)

I've tried changing the working code in a way that the obj parameter is not needed, but the inferring part stops working: it either can't be compiled at all, or can't correctly find the error of different types in the passing value parameter and the deeply-nested property.

Comment: TypeScript can't infer the `DeepKeyType` if you explictly set the type of `ObjectType`. It is simply a missing feature. The common work around is to use currying: https://tsplay.dev/WvabYm

Comment: @TobiasS. Then for the link, it's better than nothing, but still looks like a workaround to me. I guess, if it's a problem of typescript, then there is just no better solution than currying.